# Reescritura de URLs en WordPress para que incorpore un campo relacional ACF Relationship

Tags: wordpress, rewriterule

Tengo un problema con la reescritura de URLs en la siguiente estructura en WordPress:

Hay creados ahora mismo tres CPT (con CPT UI) llamados gt_cat_producto, gt_tipo y gt_serie. El primer CPT no reescribe la URL, el segundo tiene la reescritura personalizada como %gt_category% y el tercero la tiene a %gt_category%/%gt_type%, es decir, que realmente quiero crear una estructura jerárquica en la que la URL sea categoria-producto/categoria/tipo/serie (siendo categoria-producto añadido de forma fija).

Para ello, en primer lugar reescribo las tags de la siguiente forma:

```
function rewriteTagsSetup() {
    add_rewrite_tag(
        '%gt_category%',
        '([^/]+)',
        'gt_cat_producto='
    );

    add_rewrite_tag(
        '%gt_type%',
        '([^/]+)',
        'gt_tipo='
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewriteTagsSetup' );
```

Utilizando ACF Pro, tengo un campo Relacional para gt_tipo en el que se selecciona un gt_cat_producto (que será su “padre”) llamada categoria_de_producto_relacionada. Igualmente, tengo dos campos Relacionales para gt_serie en el que se selecciona un gt_cat_producto y un gt_tipo de la misma forma llamadas categoria_de_producto_relacionada y tipo_de_producto_relacionado. Estos campos son los que se sustituirán en la URL por %gt_category% y %gt_category%/%gt_type% respectivamente.

Posteriormente, realizo la reescritura de las URLs de la siguiente forma:

```
function rewriteLinkReplacements( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( empty( $post ) ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    if ( $post->post_type === 'gt_tipo' ) {
        $post_link = rewriteCategoriasProductoSlug( $post, $post_link, '%gt_category%' );
    } elseif ( $post->post_type === 'gt_serie' ) {
        $post_link = rewriteCategoriasProductoSlug( $post, $post_link, '%gt_category%' );
        $post_link = rewriteTiposProductoSlug( $post, $post_link, '%gt_type%' );
    }

    return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'rewriteLinkReplacements', 9, 2 );


function rewriteCategoriasProductoSlug( $post, $post_link, $replace ) {
    $categoriasProducto = get_field( 'categoria_de_producto_relacionada', $post->ID );

    if ( ! empty( $categoriasProducto ) ) {
        $categoriaProducto = $categoriasProducto[0];

        if ( ! empty( $categoriaProducto ) ) {
            $categoriaProductoSlug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $categoriaProducto );

            $post_link = str_replace( $replace, 'categoria-producto/' . $categoriaProductoSlug, $post_link );
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}

function rewriteTiposProductoSlug( $post, $post_link, $replace ) {
    $tiposProducto = get_field( 'tipo_de_producto_relacionado', $post->ID );

    if ( ! empty( $tiposProducto ) ) {
        $tipoProducto = $tiposProducto[0];

        if ( ! empty( $tipoProducto ) ) {
            $tipoProductoSlug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $tipoProducto );

            $post_link = str_replace( $replace, $tipoProductoSlug, $post_link );
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}
```

Esto me funciona correctamente, es decir, que si creo un gt_cat_producto llamado “vehiculo”, luego un gt_tipo llamado “coche” en donde le pongo que su relación es con “vehiculo” y luego un gt_serie llamado “ferrari” que se relaciona con “vehiculo” y “coche”, la URL que me figura es categoria-producto/vehiculo/coche/ferrari, lo que es exactamente lo que estoy buscando.

Sin embargo cuando quiero ver la página tanto del tipo (en este caso sería “coche”) como la página de la serie (en este caso sería “ferrari”) me devuelve un 404, página no encontrada. Con Elementor Pro he creado una plantilla para que se visualice en gt_tipo y otra para que se visualice en gt_serie, con lo que las plantillas existen (de hecho, si no hago redirecciones, se usan correctamente). Sin embargo, ninguna de las dos se visualiza. Sobra decir que he actualizado los enlaces permanentes incontables veces cada vez que hago un cambio.

Al final iba a utilizar una función que se inicia así (la resumo para poner sólo el de gt_tipo):

```
function templateRedirects() {
    if ( ! is_singular( 'gt_tipo' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $redirectTo = get_post_type_archive_link( 'gt_tipo' );

    // Algunas acciones extra

    wp_redirect( $redirectTo );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'templateRedirects', 10 );
```

Para obtener esa plantilla asociada a gt_tipo, pero el problema es que aquí al principio me llega directamente como que no hay nada (si pongo un global $post o un global $wp_query, me sale que la ID de la página es null), con lo que la primera condición siempre falla y no llega a obtener la plantilla.

¿Me estoy dejando algo? ¿Se puede hacer de alguna otra forma con add_rewrite_rule (lo he probado, pero obtengo peores resultados)? ¿Cómo es posible montar una estructura como la que necesito en donde la URL de un CPT dependa de la relación que tenga con otro CPT? A ser posible sin ningún plugin de pago.

Supongo que tendré que utilizar add_rewrite_rule en algún momento, pero se me escapa cómo debería hacerlo, qué opciones poner y cómo hacer que funcione, porque pruebe lo que pruebe, no cambia nada.

Gracias si podéis ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo yo mismo después de darle muchas vueltas. He conseguido realizarlo con la siguiente estructura. No conseguía que funcionara ningún add_rewrite_rule debido a que los hacía en base al CPT inicial y entraban en conflicto al tener todos el mismo texto inicial (categoria-producto), pero al final he visto que debo poner siempre el padre de todos, el gt_cat_producto, para que así funcione. Simplemente en cada regla debo añadir un hijo más. Ahora sí la plantilla funciona y accedo correctamente a la página:

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%gt_cat_producto%', '([^/]+)', 'gt_cat_producto=' );
    add_permastruct( 'gt_cat_producto', '/categoria-producto/%gt_cat_producto%', false );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^gt_cat_producto/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?gt_cat_producto=$matches[1]', 'top' );

    add_rewrite_tag( '%gt_tipo%', '([^/]+)', 'gt_tipo=' );
    add_permastruct( 'gt_tipo', '/categoria-producto/%gt_cat_producto%/%gt_tipo%', false );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^gt_cat_producto/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?gt_tipo=$matches[2]', 'top' );

    add_rewrite_tag( '%gt_serie%', '([^/]+)', 'gt_serie=' );
    add_permastruct( 'gt_serie', '/categoria-producto/%gt_cat_producto%/%gt_tipo%/%gt_serie%', false );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^gt_cat_producto/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?gt_tipo=$matches[2]&gt_serie=$matches[3]', 'top' );

    add_rewrite_tag( '%gt_subcategoria%', '([^/]+)', 'gt_subcategoria=' );
    add_permastruct( 'gt_subcategoria', '/categoria-producto/%gt_cat_producto%/%gt_tipo%/%gt_serie%/%gt_subcategoria%', false );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^gt_cat_producto/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?gt_tipo=$matches[2]&gt_serie=$matches[3]&gt_subcategoria=$matches[4]', 'top' );
}
```